# I can't ssh to any node on my batman-advanced network using its ipv6 address

Tags: networking, ssh, ipv6

I have two nodes in a batman advanced network (I plan to add more). I have the ipv6 address of the node I want to ssh to

```
fe80::8003:5aff:fed7:fb8b/64
```

but I can't seem to ssh from any other nodes in the network. I have tried:

```
ssh fe80::8003:5aff:fed7:fb8b/64

ssh root@fe80::8003:5aff:fed7:fb8b/64

ssh root@fe80::8003:5aff:fed7:fb8b

ssh -6 root@fe80::8003:5aff:fed7:fb8b%bat0

ssh -6 root@fe80::8003:5aff:fed7:fb8b%wlan0
```

but nothing seems to work. The last two options take a while (10s or so) and then return

```
ssh: connect to host fe80::8003:5aff:fed7:fb8b%bat0 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Anyone know what the issue is?

Add: Still haven't figured it out but I am trying to make sure that the ssh connections will be allowed using the following calls

```
iptables -A INPUT -i wlan0 -p tcp -s 192.168.100.0/24 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i bat0 -p tcp -s 192.168.100.0/24 --dport 22 -m state --state        NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o bat0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options

```
ssh fe80::8003:5aff:fed7:fb8b/64
ssh root@fe80::8003:5aff:fed7:fb8b/64
```

do not work, as the `/64` part is not needed here and not part of the address, but they indicate the whole subnet. You just want to connect to one host, don't you?

```
ssh root@fe80::8003:5aff:fed7:fb8b
```

would be the right syntax, but `fe80:` are link-local addresses, so the link must be given as well. (Theoretically, several hosts can have the same `fe80::` address if they are not on the same network.)

```
ssh -6 root@fe80::8003:5aff:fed7:fb8b%bat0
ssh -6 root@fe80::8003:5aff:fed7:fb8b%wlan0
```

should be right. The source for not working must be somewhere else - badly configured SSH daemon? Don't know...

Comment: Managed to get it working

Comment: ssh -6 root@fe80::8003:5aff:fed7:fb8b%wlan0 was in fact correct except I was using the bat0 ipv6 address instead of the wlan0 address